# Как получить результат в модальном окне?

Tags: javascript, html

Столкнулся с такой проблемой как отправка формы без перезагрузки страницы методом GET
Например есть форма

```html
<div class="form">
<form method="GET" action="server.php">
                    <input type="text" name="name">
                    <input type="text" name="name1">
                    <input type="text" name="name2">
                    <input type="text" name="name3">
                    <input type="text" name="name4">
                    <input type="text" name="name5">
                    <input type="text" name="name6">
                    <button type="button">Отправить</button>
                   </form>
<a href="server.php" class="form-win" data-fancybox-type="iframe"></a>
</div>
```

Которая отправляется на server.php и возвращает результат на главную страницу.
Сейчас она работает так (форма отправляется на server.php и результат отображается там же)
Как получить результат без перезагрузки страницы во всплывающем окне
Вот код всплывающего окна

```js
$(function() {
        var Btn = $('.form button');
        var Inp = $('.form input');
        var Win = $('.form-win');
        
        Btn.click(function() {
            if (Inp.val() == '') {
                alert('Введите данные');
                Inp.focus();
            }
            else {
                Win.attr('href', 'server.php?nnn=' + Inp.val());
                Win.click();
                //Win.fancybox();
            }
        });
        Inp.keypress(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                Btn.click();
            }
        });
        
        Win.fancybox({
            maxWidth    : '95%',
            maxHeight   : '95%',
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '95%',
            height      : '95%',
            autoSize    : false,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none'
        });
    });
```

Если указать button type="button" Открывается пустое модальное окно
а если указать button type="submit" То открывается страница server.php с результатом который мне нужен.
А этот результат нужно вывести в модальном окне.
Подскажите как правильно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.BATON').on('click', function(e){
  e.prevenDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: $('.form').attr('action'),
    type: $('.form').attr('method'),
    data: $('.form').serialize(),
    success: function(data){
      // data - это и есть результат который пришлет твой server.php
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="form">
<form method="GET" class="form" action="server.php">
                    <input type="text" name="name">
                    <input type="text" name="name1">
                    <input type="text" name="name2">
                    <input type="text" name="name3">
                    <input type="text" name="name4">
                    <input type="text" name="name5">
                    <input type="text" name="name6">
                    <button type="submit" class="BATON">Отправить</button>
                   </form>
<a href="server.php" class="form-win" data-fancybox-type="iframe"></a>
</div>
```